# Can any continuous function $\phi : J → \mathbb{C}$ on a closed bounded connected subset $J ⊂ \mathbb{C}$ be uniformly approximated by polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** The Weierstrass approximation theorem states that any continuous function $f : I → \mathbb{R}$ on a
closed bounded connected subset $I ⊂ \mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. Can
any continuous function $\phi : J → \mathbb{C}$ on a closed bounded connected subset $J ⊂ \mathbb{C}$ be uniformly
approximated by polynomials? Justify your answer.

**Question:** While discussing with a friend I was given the following argument. I am not really sure about its correctness, can someone help to verify any misconceptions? I'd appreciate any other (simpler) arguments as well!

The Weierstrass approximation theorem states that any continuous function $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ on a closed bounded connected subset $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. However, this result does not directly extend to functions on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ due to the lack of a natural ordering in the complex numbers.

Instead, a generalization known as the Stone-Weierstrass theorem applies to functions on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $J$ be a closed bounded connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The space of continuous complex-valued functions on $J$ is denoted by $C(J, \mathbb{C})$.

The Stone-Weierstrass theorem asserts that any subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of the algebra $C(J, \mathbb{C})$ that separates points (i.e., for any distinct $z_1, z_2 \in J$, there exists a function $f \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $f(z_1) \neq f(z_2)$) and contains the constant functions is dense in $C(J, \mathbb{C})$ with respect to the uniform norm.

To approximate a continuous function $\phi : J \to \mathbb{C}$ uniformly by polynomials, one needs to find a suitable subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ that satisfies the conditions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. If such a subalgebra exists, it implies that polynomials can uniformly approximate $\phi$.

Keep in mind that the choice of $\mathcal{A}$ depends on the specific properties of the function $\phi$ and the set $J$. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem does not provide a unique subalgebra for all cases, but it guarantees the existence of such subalgebras under certain conditions.

Comment: This is a totally reasonable problem and post, but I have to ask--- is your friend ChatGPT?

Comment: Certainly not. A continuous  function on the closed unit disk cannot be uniformly approximated by polynomials unless it is holomorphic in the open unit disk.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing what the lack of a natural ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ has to do with the failure of the Weierstrass theorem for $\mathbb{C}$. (The issue with the extension is that a polynomial $P(x, y)$ is not necessarily a polynomial in $z = x+ iy$, and the actual problem is what @geetha290krm said above.)

Comment: Easy Jordan Curve Theorem counterexamples: let $J$ be the unit circle and $\phi$ be in injective with with index $-1$ (negative orientation), then $\phi$ cannot be uniformly approximated by polynomials (which obey the Argument Principle).  In general something with negative index cannot be closely approximated by something with non-negative index.

Comment: @user8675309 Why make it so complicated? Elementary CA shows that $\overline z$ cannot be approximated by polynomial in $z$ in the close unit disk.

Comment: @geetha290krm I wanted to emphasize geometric properties that arise in $\mathbb C$ and I think this is best done with the index. Yes, of course $\phi(z) = \bar z$ is an obvious example of injective with index $-1$ on the unit circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give an elementary argument to show that this is not true. No theorem from Complex Analysis is needed for this proof. This proof is self-contained.

Let $J=\{z: |z|\leq 1\}$ and $f(z)=\overline z$. Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle defined by $\gamma (t)=e^{it}, 0\le t\le 2\pi$. For a continuous function $g$ on $\{z:|z|=1\}$ define $\int_{\gamma} g(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi} g(e^{it})ie^{it}dt$. Observe that $|\int_{\gamma} g(z)dz| \le 2\pi M$ if $|g(z)| \le M$ for all $z$. (1)
It is very easy to check from definition that $\int_{\gamma} z^{n}dz=2\pi i$ if $n=-1$ and $0$ if $n$ is any integer $\neq 1$. Note that $f(z)= z^{-1}$ when $|z|=1$

Suppose there is a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(z)-p(z)|<\frac 1 2$ for all $z \in J$. Consider $\int_{\gamma} [f(z)-p(z)]dz $. Using above statements we see that  the value of this integral Is $2\pi i-0=2\pi i$. But $|\int_{\gamma} [f(z)-p(z)]dz| \le (\frac 1 2)(2\pi)$ by (1). This gives us $2\pi =|2\pi i| \le \pi$, a contradiction.

On the other hand, if you are considering polynomials in two real variables $x$ and $y$, the real and imaginary parts of $z$,  then result is true and it follows from the fact that such polynomials form an algebra which contains constants, separates points and is closed under complex conjugation. Stone-Weirstarss Therom is applicable and no ordering of points of $\mathbb R^{2}$ is needed.